# Excel: Copy value down a column until first blank cell in another column?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm hoping to find a way to copy a cell value down Column B until the first blank cell in Column E. What I have is basically this:

[image]

But what I would like to have happen automatically is this:

[image]

Is there a way to make the product name copy down Column B automatically whenever a new ingredient is added in Column E, and then start over with a new product name when a new product is added (after a blank row).

Comment: This data has a pretty obvious pattern, but per your comment below, is not representative of the real data.  Can you please instead use some mock data that's more inline with what you'll be using?  Also, are the users adding data to column E only? Or column B? Or Both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `Worksheet.Change` event to do this. This code goes in the sheet module. It may need tweaked but basically does the following:

1. When cell(s) in the worksheet change, checks if the cell is in Column E. I assume that you'd be entering ingredients one at a time, so the `For each rng...` might be overkill.
2. Checks if the cell is not the first ingredient in a new product list. The easiest way I thought of doing that was checking if the cell above it is not blank, and that the cell one row above and three columns to the left (i.e. where the product name is populated) is not blank as well.
3. If the previous two conditions are met, "copies" the Product name down a row.

So each new product name **must** be entered manually, skipping a line after the previous product, and the filling down will happen with the 2nd ingredient on.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each rng In Target
        If Not Intersect(rng, Columns(5)) Is Nothing Then
            If rng.Row > 1 And Not IsEmpty(rng.Offset(-1)) And Not IsEmpty(rng.Offset(-1, -3)) Then
                rng.Offset(, -3).Value = rng.Offset(-1, -3).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next rng

ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help, maybe you can suggest a modification for the code I've added to the original post?

Comment: If it is working but slow, probably better to ask as a question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). With a quick glance, you definitely don't need to repeat `On Error GoTo ErrHandler` and `Application.EnableEvents = False`, and you should only loop through `Each rng in Target` once.

Comment: The code works fine, I just had to update my workbook with named ranges and fewer volatile formulas and now it runs smoothly. Thanks again for your help, I'll delete my edit.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add ingredients to column E manually, you can use a formula in C.

In cell `C3` put this formula and drag down as far as needed:

```
=IF(AND(E2<>"",E3<>""),"Product "&COUNTBLANK($E2:$E$3)+1,IF(AND($E2="",ISBLANK($E2),$E3<>""),"Product "&COUNTBLANK($E$2:$E2),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful, but unfortunately my product names are not actually Product 1, Product 2, Product 3, etc.. I or another user will still be manually entering unique names in that column. I'm hoping the formula can copy the new unique value each time. Is this possible?

Comment: @DanC - Can you clarify in your OP - how is the data being entered then? Are your users entering information in column C, or column E?  If they're entering the "Product 1" name, what should the ingredient be?  Instead of a relatively patterened example, can you update your OP with some "real" data (doesn't have to literally be the data you have, just make something up).

Comment: I just updated the post with more realistic data. Users will enter data in multiple columns, not just column B, but I only want it to copy those values based on new entries in column E (ingredients)

Answer (score 0):

This is not inherently "Automatic" but each time it's run it will fill in your product names.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim oPrevName As String
    oPrevName = ""

    For icounter = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheet1.Cells(icounter, 5).Value <> "" Then
            If Sheet1.Cells(icounter, 2).Value <> oPrevName And Sheet1.Cells(icounter, 2).Value <> "" Then
                oPrevName = Sheet1.Cells(icounter, 2).Value
            End If
            Sheet1.Cells(icounter, 2).Value = oPrevName
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

We store the previous non-blank name found in the product column (2).  If there is an ingredient listed on the same row (in Column 5), we add the stored product name.

Comment: Updated: Ingredient column to 5 (E), instead of 4 (D).